# Accessing Steam Guard File

Tags: steam

I am trying to use a [Python package](https://github.com/bukson/steampy#examples) from GitHub with which I can access many information on steam: . However, in order to log in, I would need to provide use the path to my "Steam Guard File".

Or get this information:

```
{
    "steamid": "YOUR_STEAM_ID_64",
    "shared_secret": "YOUR_SHARED_SECRET",
    "identity_secret": "YOUR_IDENTITY_SECRET"
}
```

In order to access the information, I need to login using:

```
steam_client = SteamClient('MY_API_KEY')
steam_client.login('MY_USERNAME', 'MY_PASSWORD', 'PATH_TO_STEAMGUARD_FILE')
```

There was [another site](https://github.com/SteamTimeIdler/stidler/wiki/Getting-your-%27shared_secret%27-code-for-use-with-Auto-Restarter-on-Mobile-Authentication#getting-shared-secret-from-steam-desktop-authenticator-windows) Github page recommended to access this information, but it was mainly for mobile Steam Guard and I use my email address.

Can anyone help me to access the path to this Steam Guard file or the information it contains?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This may be better suited for Stackoverflow, but you are going to want to include a minimal, reproducible sample of code as well or at least show what you have so far.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of asking it there too, but as this is not explicitly a coding question I thought I would post it here first.

Comment: And be careful with providing that kind of information. I suppose this is an offline or client-side file, but make sure no one else has access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find your Steam Guard File in your Program Files (x86) / Steam Folder:

[image]

Please remember to not give anyone access to this file, as it could compromise your Account.

(The hidden file seems to be a honeypot, so you shouldn't need it)